# How to call useQuery as an async task

Tags: react-native, graphql, react-hooks, apollo, apollo-client

I am new to `React Native` and `Apollo-Client`. In my Screen there are three tabs and individual tabs is calling its own data. But due to `useQuery` UI is completely freezing and giving a very bad experience.

Is there any other way that I can call the `useQuery` in async manner or in any background task?

**EDIT**

```
function PlayerList(props) {

    const [loading , setloading] = useState(true)
    const [data, setData] = useState()
    const [loadData, { tempLoading, tempError, tempData }] = useLazyQuery(query);
   

   async function getData(){
        loadData()
   }

    useEffect(() => {

        if (tempData == undefined) {
            getData()
        }

    })

     if(tempLoading){
           return 
                <View >....</View>
     }
     if(tempData) {
          return ( <View> ... </View>) }

 }
```

Please find the above code for better understanding.

Comment: Apollo Client uses fetch under the hood, which is always asynchronous. It sounds like something else is going on. You should edit your question to include the relevant code.

Comment: @DanielRearden , please look the edited one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apollo Client uses fetch which is always asynchronous. The issue is that you are creating an infinite loop.

- The object returned by the `useLazyQuery` hook you are destructuring does not have properties named `tempLoading`, `tempError` or `tempData`. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names) for how to correctly rename variables when using destructuring syntax.
- Because `tempData` is always undefined, your `useEffect` hook's callback will be called on every render.
- Calling `loadData` on every render triggers another render.

By using `useLazyQuery`, you are unnecessarily complicating your code -- you should be using `useQuery` instead.

```
const { data, loading } = useQuery(query)
if (loading) {
  return <View>....</View>
}
return <View>...</View>
```

Comment: Thanks for updating about Apollo Client being the asynchronous. My issue was my UI was not getting updated properly after fetching the data.